# Can JS/jQuery interact with audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm writing a page for a musician and am excited about using the HTML5 `<audio>` tag to create a custom player. I'd also like to experiment with some kind of visual feedback from the music being played. Are there any JavaScript experiments/libraries/APIs that exploit this idea? Is it even possible?

**EDIT:** It's indeed possible. [Here](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html) is an impressive list of apps using the Chrome Web Audio API. I'd still love to see what you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's possible in Firefox

Spectrum Visualization:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/spectrum-visualization-with-the-html5-audio-data-api

Mozilla Audio API:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API

But I'm not sure about other browsers... I couldn't find much else on the topic.